# How to aggregate data within a time window to a specific date in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset like:

```
New_ID     application_start_date  is_approved
1234       2022-03-29              1
2345       2022-01-29              1
1234       2021-02-28              0
567        2019-07-03              1
567        2018-09-01              0
```

And I want to create new attributes `N_App_3M` which would be sum of `is_approved` to that `application_start_date` within 3 month time frame.

Expected output would be:

```
New_ID     application_start_date  is_approved  N_App_3M
1234       2022-03-29              1            2
2345       2022-01-29              0            0
1234       2022-02-28              1            1
567        2019-07-03              1            1
567        2018-09-01              0            0
```

Comment: What is your expected output? Also could you provide a larger sample dataset?

Comment: The expected output in `N_App_3M` would be `application_start_date`+ 3 months?

Comment: @VictorCaicedo That would be sum of "is_approved" within the last 3 months until that given "application_start_date"

Comment: shouldn't the 2 be with the 2022-03-29 date rather than 2022-02-29?

Comment: @mozway Ups, typo, sorry.. Good catch!

Comment: Your third row "2021-02-29" is not a valid date

Comment: @not_speshal It's just dummy data but good catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute the rolling 3-month and 7-day sums and then use `pd.merge_asof` to generate your columns:

```
df["application_start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["application_start_date"])
df = df.set_index("application_start_date").sort_index()
app_3M = df.resample("M")["is_approved"].sum().rolling(3).sum().rename("N_App_3M").fillna(0)
app_7D = df.rolling("7D")["is_approved"].sum().rename("N_App_7D").fillna(0)

output = pd.merge_asof(df,app_3M,direction="nearest",left_index=True,right_index=True)
output = pd.merge_asof(output,app_7D,direction="nearest",left_index=True,right_index=True)

>>> output
                        New_ID  is_approved  N_App_3M  N_App_7D
application_start_date                                         
2018-09-01                 567            0       0.0       0.0
2019-07-03                 567            1       0.0       1.0
2021-02-28                1234            0       0.0       0.0
2022-01-29                2345            1       1.0       1.0
2022-03-29                1234            1       2.0       1.0
```

Comment: TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

Comment: See the first line. You might need to add that.